# Datetime formatter of python works for one string and does not for another

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime, format

I have a dictionary whose keys needs to be converted to a datetime object and format it to an understandable format. This is the dictionary

```
blah =  {
            "COLUMNNAME": "Some thing",
            "RID": 6,
            "Y202009": 15791.68,
            "Y202006": 8149.99,
            "Y202003": 27252.75,
            "Y201912": 19885.85,
            "Y201909": 18748.21,
            "rowno": 5.0
        }
```

And this is the function to convert the keys into desired format

```
def dict_process(idict):
    del idict["RID"]
    del idict['rowno']
    for key, val in idict.items():
        try:
            new_key = str(datetime.strptime(key,"Y%Y%m").strftime("%Y %b"))
            idict[new_key] = idict.pop(key)
        except:
            None
    return None
```

But this function returns a dictionary which is like this

```
{'COLUMNNAME': 'Net Sales',
 'Y201912': 19885.85,
 'Y201909': 18748.21,
 '2020 Sep': 15791.68,
 '2020 Jun': 8149.99,
 '2020 Mar': 27252.75}
```

Could anyone help me with why the formatter is not working for years that contain 2019?

Comment: I can't replicate this.

Comment: @MattDMo try after importing the datetime library. "from datetime import datetime"

Comment: I did, only I just imported `datetime` and adjusted your code to use `datetime.datetime.strptime...`

Comment: Try: `new_key = str(datetime.strptime(key[1:], "%Y%m").strftime("%Y %b"))`

Comment: @pavel nope... not working....

Comment: `str(datetime.strptime('Y201912', "Y%Y%m").strftime("%Y-%b"))` this is working fine individually. But no idea why this does not work inside the function

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea, sorry. What you can try is to remove the `try`/`except` block and see if any exceptions are raised.